# Changing the starting point of a Panel in WinForm C#

Tags: c#, windows, panel, slidingdrawer

I want to Change my starting top-left point of a panel , that is the main starting point of panels , to top-right starting point.
In other word, I want to reverse it.
the Timer object calls the event every 30 milliseconds.
and it visibles the panel and changes its width from 0 to 140.
it's height is unchangeable.

```
  private void SettingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            settingPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(699, 77);
            settingPanel.Visible = (settingPanel.Visible ? false : true);
            settingPanel.Size = (settingPanel.Visible ? new Size(0, 355) : new Size(140, 355));
            slidingTimer.Start();
        }

        private void SlidingTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (settingPanel.Visible)
            {
                if (settingPanel.Width <= 140)
                {
                    settingPanel.Width += 20;
                    this.Refresh();
                }
                else
                {
                    slidingTimer.Stop();
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Did you need to change the `Location = new Point(x, y)` ?

Comment: _In other word, I want to reverse it_ You can't really do that, but it is quite unclear what you actually want to achieve. Change the location and create a sliding effect? just do it. Note that you would have to change the Left, not the X property! You can't reverse a control to show a mirorred  content, though. You can reverse a graphics object to show mirorred graphics content, though. - Consider changing the control.Bounds property to reduce flicker..